# Aligning a logo with a menu

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to align a simple nav bar with the logo on the left and the menu + searchbar on the right. I just can't figure out how to get them horizontally aligned. I'm working mobile first with media queries. I feel like this should have a really simple fix but I just can't see it.

here's my HTML and CSS

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 1499px) and (min-width: 1153px) {
  .navbar-toggle,
  .main-nav .social {
    display: none;
  }
  .main-nav {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    display: inline;
    border: none;
  }
  .main-nav a {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .navbardesk {
    display: flex;
  }
  .logo {
    order: 0;
  }
  .mainnav {
    order: 1;
  }
  .searchicon {
    order: 3;
  }
  header {
    max-width: 1153px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<header>

  <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </span>

  <div class="navbardesk">
    <h1 class="logo">Buurtsuper Leo van der Drift</h1>

    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Over ons</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Kantoren en bedrijven</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="nav-links">Bestellen</a></li>
      <li class="nav-links social"> <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></li>
    </ul>

    <i class="fas fa-search searchicon"></i>
  </div>

  <p class="welkomtekst">
    Welkom !<br> Bij buurtsuper Leo v.d. Drift bent u aan het juiste adres als het gaat om verse producten.
  </p>
</header>
```

oh and here's the codepen:
https://codepen.io/radartrinkets/project/editor/XgWOvG

Comment: If you're going to use some CSS library, you need to tag that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "flex" to align items.
Example:

```
.v-align{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
}
```

And you use "v-align" class on parent div of menu and logo, it will center your content on X and Y axis. if you want to lose X axis, you can delete "justify-content" part

Comment: I thought I'd already done that with 


.navbardesk {
    display: flex;
  }